# Detect specific value change in Pandas DataSeries

Tags: python, pandas

I want to detect a specific change of the value of a DataSeries in Pandas.
Given I got a DataSeries of the following Format:

```
ds = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 1, 'f': 5, 'g': 2}
```

With DataSeries built in diff(1) function I am able to detect a value change and how big it was. Is it possible to only get the occurances where the value changes from 4 to 1?

Comment: If you know the start and end point, there is no real interest in computing the diff ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare original values by `4` and shifted by `1` and for count `True`s use `sum`:

```
ds = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 1, 'f': 5, 'g': 2}
s = pd.Series(ds)

s = (s.eq(4) & s.shift(-1).eq(1)).sum()
print (s)
1
```

**Details**:

```
print (s.eq(4) & s.shift(-1).eq(1))
a    False
b    False
c    False
d     True
e    False
f    False
g    False
dtype: bool
```